# Vertical Scrolling on Links with fullPage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I'm using the fullPage.js plugin to develop a project. The plugin works fine, but I have one question:

I have some sliders within a section so as to create vertical scrolling. However, within one slider I have different links that I also want to trigger vertical scrolling in the same way as the plugin does. Here's how my structure looks like:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">
       <div class="slide"> Slide 1 </div>
       <div class="slide">
          <a href="#example">Example</a>
          ...
       </div>
       <div class="slide" id="example"> Slide 3 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, just like I click on the arrows and the different sliders appear, is it possible to click on a link and then a specific slider to appear? The idea is that the Slide 3 will contain content that will change depending on the link that is clicked.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to achieve. Try to explain it in another way.

Comment: HI Alvaro. Finally I managed to solve this problem. Basically, I wanted to navigate to different slides. So I noticed that the plugin provides this functionality by setting the href something like this: `<a href="#section/2">...</a>`